# Python - splitting strings at second hyphen

Tags: python, string, split

I want to follow a pattern of spliting `artist - track` strings at the `'-'` separator, like so:

```
s = 'At the Drive-In - Incurably Innocent'
```

but, like above, sometimes the artist name has the `'-'`, as well.

if I `s.plit('-')[-1]`, it prints: `Incurably Innocent`,

but I would like to split only the second `'-'` ocurrence, and end up with:

`['At the Drive-In', 'Incurably Innocent']`, using a one-liner.

how do I do it?

Comment: You could split on `' - '`..

Comment: @thebjorn that would be the only way to get this output, because of the spaces.

Comment: it works, but what is the logic?

Comment: the logic is that you have space-hyphen-space so split works (split is multi-char)

Comment: Maybe `.split(' - ')`? If it is guaranteed there are spaces between artist and '-' and track and no space near '-' in artist name.

Comment: @thebjorn I think this answer is error proof, that is, even if track name has hyphen (because it will not have space). If you answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Moses has already answered, you should accept his answer -- I've given him an upvote :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the track name is not going to contain any `' - '`, you can use `str.rsplit` on `' - '`:

```
>>> s.rsplit(' - ', 1) # split once
['At the Drive-In', 'Incurably Innocent']
```

Comment: It is incorrect as per the OPs requirement *I would like to split only the second '-'*. For strings like `'At the Drive-In - Incurably - Innocent'` (with three hyphens), it will give incorrect result

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I think the text you've quoted only refers to the example they gave